# When I run "eb ssh environment-name", where am I SSHing into?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Where am I SSHing into when using `eb ssh <environment name>`? The instance? What if there are multiple instances? Will my app actually be on here? Is there a way for me to know for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to the instance. If there are multiple instances, from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html):

> If an environment has multiple running instances, EB CLI **prompts you to specify which instance** you want to connect to.

Yes, your application will be in `/var/app/current` if it is successful deployed. If not, it may be in `/var/app/staging`.

Comment: Thank you. I am using docker-compose with a node.js app (with ts). Since adding TS things ain't working no more. So if I SSH into and navigate to /var/app/current I can see my .docker-compose and docker-file... along with other files and my src folder (contains my node.js app). On this instance, what happens? Will it run my docker-compose.yml and create a docker container on the image. I thought this instance was going to have whatever the execution of docker-compose.yml applied to it and I would be SSHing into that. I'm very confused

Comment: I would have thought that dockerizing most things, which work locally when runing docker-compose would be deployable on elastic beanstalk without a bunch of stress. Any pointers for what may have gone wrong or how to debug this?

Comment: @Prof You can run `docker ps` to see any docker containers running. One should be your application. It would be best if you made new question with details of your docker deployment. Your current question is very generic and ask only about sshing into the instance, for which I provided an answer. Without new details, best in new question, its difficult to speculate why your application does not work.